# Replace all instances of a character if it occurres before another character

Tags: bash, text-processing

I need to be able to export some variables from a file, so that I can use it in my BASH script. the file content is something like this:

```
my.variable.var1=a-long-ling.with.lot_of_different:characters:and_numbers
my.variable.another.var2=another-long-ling.with.lot_of_different:characters:and_numbers
my.variable.number3=yet_another_long-ling.with.lot_of_different:characters:and_numbers
```

First I tried sourcing it using `source` as they are and got the error message saying: `command not found`. I tried using `export`, which gave me error message saying: `not a valid identifier`.

I think I can only export if I change my variable from `my.variable.var1` to `my_variable_var1`.
I am able to do this by cutting the line at `=` and then replacing all `.`s with `_`s and then adding the variables back.

So my question is, is it possible to change:

```
my.variable.var1=a-long-ling.with.lot_of_different:characters:and_numbers
my.variable.another.var2=another-long-ling.with.lot_of_different:characters:and_numbers
my.variable.number3=yet_another_long-ling.with.lot_of_different:characters:and_numbers
```

to

```
my_variable_var1=a-long-ling.with.lot_of_different:characters:and_numbers
my_variable_another_var2=another-long-ling.with.lot_of_different:characters:and_numbers
my_variable_number3=yet_another_long-ling.with.lot_of_different:characters:and_numbers
```

using any of those cool 'one liners'? Would love to use that, plus a good learning.

Comment: 1. are those variable definitions all on one line (and word- wrapped here) or are there newlines embedded in them?  2. when setting a variable, you  put quotes around the value, not the variable name.  use quotes around the variable names when you use them later.  e.g. `var="value" ; echo "$var"`.  if the value is a static string (i.e. with no $variables etc in it) you can and should use a single quote, e.g. `var='value' ; echo "$var"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed -e :1 -e 's/^\([^=]*\)\./\1_/;t1'
```

That is replace a sequence of characters other than `.` at the beginning of the line followed by `.` by that same sequence and `_`, and repeat the process until it no longer matches.

With `awk`:

```
awk -F = -v OFS== '{gsub(/\./, "_", $1); print}'
```

Now, in case the right hand side of the `=` contains characters special to the shell (`\`"$&();'#~<>...`, space, tab, other blanks...), you may want to quote it:

```
sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g;:1"'
     s/^\([^=]*\)\./\1_/;t1'"
     s/=/='/;s/\$/'/"
```

Or:

```
awk -F = -v q="'" -v OFS== '
   {gsub(q, q "\\" q q)
    gsub(/\./, "_", $1)
    $2 = q $2
    print $0 q}'
```

Comment: or `awk -F = -v OFS== '{gsub(/\./, "_", $1); gsub(/=/,"='\"); gsub(/$/,"\""); print}' abhinav.txt` to also put double-quotes around the value of each variable.

Comment: I remember you have said the space between `-F =` was required by POSIX. I looked up the documentation but could not find it. Would you please showing me that requirement.

Comment: don't have a posix ref but without the space, getopt(3) will intepret the `=` as defining the field separator to be whatever comes after the `=`.  With the space, getopt(3) knows that you mean a literal `=`.

Comment: seems to make no difference on `gawk` and `mawk`.  `original-awk` didn't like any of the forms i tried (even after deleting `-v OFS==` because it didn't like any of the forms i tried to specify that OFS should be an `=`)

Comment: @cas: AFAICT, POSIX said in [Utility Syntax Guideline](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) that `Each option and option-argument should be a separate argument` but allow exception as described in [Utility Argument Syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_01)

Comment: @cas: And it said `If the SYNOPSIS of a standard utility shows an option with a mandatory option-argument (as with [ -c option_argument] in the example), a conforming application shall use separate arguments for that option and its option-argument. However, a conforming implementation shall also permit applications to specify the option and option-argument in the same argument string without intervening <blank> characters.` `awk` documentation shown that `[-F sepstring]`, so it must be allowed to use `[-Fsepstring]`, mustn't it?

Comment: works with `original-awk` too, but you have to move `OFS==` inside the script with `'BEGIN {OFS="="} ...`, in which case you may as well drop the `-F =` and do `'BEGIN {FS=OFS="="} ...'`

Comment: @cuonglm, that's about the SYNOPSIS in the spec not in the man page on the system. Note that the wording has changed in the latest  version of the spec. So `-Fx` and `-va=b` should now work (in systems conforming to that latest spec), but you still shouldn't use it (go figure). In practice `-va=b` still doesn't work on Solaris (`-F=` is OK though).

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash`:

```
while IFS='=' read -r i j; do echo "${i//./_}=$j" ; done
```

We have used parameter expansion pattern `${i//./_}` to replace all `.`s with `_`s in the variable name.

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt 
my.variable.var1=a-long-ling.with.lot_of_different:characters:and_numbers
my.variable.another.var2=another-long-ling.with.lot_of_different:characters:and_numbers
my.variable.number3=yet_another_long-ling.with.lot_of_different:characters:and_numbers

$ while IFS='=' read -r i j; do echo "${i//./_}=$j" ; done <file.txt 
my_variable_var1=a-long-ling.with.lot_of_different:characters:and_numbers
my_variable_another_var2=another-long-ling.with.lot_of_different:characters:and_numbers
my_variable_number3=yet_another_long-ling.with.lot_of_different:characters:and_numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another `sed`:

```
sed 'h;s/\./_/g;G;s/=.*=/=/'
```

This one does only two substitutions, irrespective of the number of dots preceding the `=` so with an input like:

```
my.var.an.other.var.with.many.dots=line.with.many:chars:and_numbers.and.stuff
```

the result is

```
my_var_an_other_var_with_many_dots=line.with.many:chars:and_numbers.and.stuff
```

This works OK when there's one `=` char per line (as in your sample input).
A more generic approach that always replaces only up to the first `=` (and only if the line contains at least one `=`) even if there are multiple `=` chars per line:

```
sed '/=/{                   # if line matches =
h                           # copy pattern space over the hold space
s/\./_/g                    # replace all . with =
G                           # append hold space content to pattern space
s/=.*\n[^=]*=/=/            # replace from the first = up to the first = after
}'                          # the newline character with a single =
```

or

```
sed -e '/=/{h;s/\./_/g;G;s/=.*\n[^=]*=/=/' -e '}'
```

so with an input like:

```
my.var.with.many.dots.but.no.equal.sign.and.stuff
my.var.with.many.dots=line.with.many:chars:numbers_and.stuff
other.var.with.many.dots=and.with.more.than=one.equal.sign=and.stuff
```

it outputs:

```
my.var.with.many.dots.but.no.equal.sign.and.stuff
my_var_with_many_dots=line.with.many:chars:numbers_and.stuff
other_var_with_many_dots=and.with.more.than=one.equal.sign=and.stuff
```